# What can I use instead of $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in PHP for consistent data regarding the referring link?

Tags: php, redirect, http-referer

I looked up the manual on php.net for $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] and it explicity says that it is unreliable depending on the browser being used on the client side. Is there a consistent replacement that I can use to redirect websites to the referring link?

EDIT: I didn't realize the error in my question until someone pointed it out in the comments - this is for an internal url as I'm trying to auto-redirect the sign-out button so a user doesn't have to see a separate message like 'you have been successfully logged out'

Comment: no, http is a stateless protocol. sessions\js are an options but will never be a 100% solution

Comment: Nope. Anything that is available to you can be spoofed by the client (or dropped completely)

Comment: i can use sessions then, but why would sessions not a be 100% solution?

Comment: because the user can just delete the session id.

Comment: sessions will be useles if user came from other site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass the location to go back to in the sign-out link\button. if its a link you can add it to the url, if a button a hidden form field.

```
<a href="/sign-out.php?back=CURRENT_URL">
```

form

```
<input type="hidden" name="back" value="CURRENT_URL">
```

CURRENT_URL =`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, or what ever is appropriate for your system.

Answer (score 1):

In short no, and do not rely on HTTP_REFERER either as its unreliable and unsafe.

From the PHP manual:

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is to use javascript for that, something like this:

```
<?php
echo "<script>history.go(-1);</script>";
?>
```